# How do I convince the l3 team that g-type arguments are necessary?

Tags: latex3, xparse

I claim that `g`-type `xparse` arguments are strictly necessary and should be supported directly in the LaTeX kernel, rather than being officially deprecated as they are right now. If you disagree with me, please explain to me how to make the following interface work without them. (The following syntax follows the one from [SemanTeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/semantex), but don’t worry about this right now.)

We imagine that we want a collection of commands corresponding to the *variables* we are using. The variable *a* will be called `\va`, the variable *b* will be `\vb`, etc.
Each variable will support an optional keyval syntax, and it’s natural to use optional brackets `[...]` for this purpose. So our syntax so far is

```
\va[<keyval syntax>]
\vb[<keyval syntax>]
...
```

So a typical math equation would look something like this:

```
\va[power=2] + \vb[power=2] = \vc[power=2] % this should print a^2 + b^2 = c^2
```

So far, so good. Then we run into the issue that many variables can also be used as *functions*. For instance, the variable *x* might depend on a variable *t*, so we might want to write *x*(*t*). In fact, this happens so often that it’s cumbersome to even distinguish between variables and functions. So let us just agree that from now on, functions are just a special case of variables. In conclusion, all variables need to be able to take arguments.

Looking at the standard TeX syntax, the most natural syntax for variables taking arguments is

```
\va[<keyval syntax>]{<argument>}
\vb[<keyval syntax>]{<argument>}
...
```

Now how are we supposed to make this work?

### First bad idea: Use an `m`-type argument

We could of course use `m`-type arguments. But then our equation from above suddenly becomes

```
\va[power=2]{} + \vb[power=2]{} = \vc[power=2]{} % this should print a^2 + b^2 = c^2
```

This feels a *lot* less natural. It’s very cumbersome to have to write `{}` after each and every variable we use. Furthermore, imagine that the value of the function is itself a function, which happens quite often (you cannot do Category Theory without it). How are we supposed to type `F(f)(x)` with this solution?

Great, so let’s discard this idea.

### Second bad idea: Use a `d()`-type argument

Next, we could try using optional arguments in ordinary parentheses, i.e. an argument of type `d()`. Then our syntax becomes

```
\va[<keyval syntax>](<argument>)
\vb[<keyval syntax>](<argument>)
...
```

I admit that this is a tempting solution, especially since math arguments are usually also printed using parentheses. However, there are at least two big problems:

- The syntax does not fit naturally into the general TeX syntax. It feels uncommon and unfamiliar to use parentheses for command arguments. In TeX, we are used to type arguments in `[...]` and `{...}`, the first type being mainly for options, the second one being mainly for “actual” arguments. We are used to `(` and `)` being meant for parentheses in equations; they usually do not have any syntactic meaning as part of command constructions.
- Nesting commands can cause issues. Sure, `xparse` is usually pretty good at recognizing nested commands. But there are some things `xparse` cannot help us with. For instance, suppose we set up the variable `\vf` so that its argument is printed in projective coordinates, i.e. `\vf(\va,\vb,\vc)` prints `f[a:b:c]`. Now if I type `\vf(\va,\vg(\vb,\vc))`, this will expand once to `f[\va:\vg(\vb:\vc)]`, and now `\vg` will no longer recognize `\vb` and `\vc` as two distinct arguments, but as one single argument `\vb:\vc`.

### Third bad idea: Use two optional `o`-type arguments

Then the syntax becomes

```
\va[<keyval syntax>][<argument>]
\vb[<keyval syntax>][<argument>]
...
```

I think we can all see the issues with this solution. If you just want to print `a(x)`, with no keyval syntax, you now have to type `\va[][\vx]`, which does not feel natural. Furthermore, this syntax has the same nesting issues as the second bad solution.

### The only remaining solution: Use `g`-type arguments

The only remaining solution is to use an optional argument in braces, i.e. an argument of type `g`:

```
\va[<keyval syntax>]{<argument>}
\vb[<keyval syntax>]{<argument>}
...
```

Then we can type `\va[power=2]` and `\va{\vx}`, and both feel equally natural. There are no nesting issues, no need to constantly print an extra, empty pair of brackets of any kind. And the syntax fits naturally into the general TeX syntax. And you can write `F(f)(x)` by typing `\vF{\vf}{\vx}`.

### My question

As I said above, if you really think `g`-type arguments should be deprecated and avoided, as is the current LaTeX policy, please provide me with an alternative syntax that solves the issues presented here. Otherwise, it is simply wrong not to include them in the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116536/discussion-on-question-by-gaussler-how-do-i-convince-the-l3-team-that-g-type-arg).

Answer (score 4):

This is borderline a meta question or opinion-based, but I think two aspects can be answered.

For *discussion* as opposed to direct *questions*, TeX-sx is not a great platform. As such, talking about the issue here is likely not to work that well: the 'best' we have is a dedicated chat space. More generally, talking to developers about their code is best done by communicating with them more-or-less directly. In the case of the LaTeX team, the [LaTeX-L mailing list](https://listserv.uni-heidelberg.de/cgi-bin/wa?A0=latex-l) is the place to go.

On the question of deprecations in `xparse`, it's important to note that what's happened is that most of the ideas were moved to the kernel. The remaining ideas have been retained in a stub `xparse`. At the time of writing (November 2020), there are a few minor technical re-arrangements outstanding, but essentially the stub is frozen. If there are out-and-out bugs they will be fixed, but there will be no significant additions. On the other hand, the stub will not be removed: `xparse` has been widely used now for many years, and whilst the team feel that some aspects do not warrant a move to the LaTeX kernel, dropping them would break too many packages/documents to be a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: So the stub is frozen. Does that mean that the part of `xparse` that have been moved to the kernel are also frozen? Or will `xparse` be a pile of buggy legacy code that is not receiving the maintenance that the kernel part is receiving?

Comment: @Gaussler As I said, for the 'stub' out-and-out bugs will be fixed; I'd also expect the code to adapt to any changes in recommended `expl3` coding style (it's part of the `latex3` repository, after all)

Comment: @Gaussler The code moved to the kernel is used by increasing parts of LaTeX itself: we will of course look after it in the same way as anything else. (As I've said, there are some outstanding code loaded by the kernel moves of a technical nature: currently the code resides in the `latex3` rpeo, it will move to `latex2e`.)

Comment: I think, third aspect can be answered, but it is impossible now.

Comment: @wipet Which third aspect? I felt that the discussion about syntax itself didn't fit; do you mean the idea that one can always 'roll ones own'?